# Center Masonry layout that has different sized images

Tags: javascript, jquery, layout, jquery-masonry

I've run into a problem trying to keep Masonry centered while using three different image sizes in the grid.

JS:

```js
$('#container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    //isFitWidth: true, // This setting ignores my max-width or width settings for #container but gives me the result that I'm looking for
    columnWidth: 155
});
```

CSS:

```css
#container {
    max-width: 940px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #container {
        max-width: 728px;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="item">item</li>
        <li class="item">item</li>
        <li class="item">item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Masonry works as expected when using the default width (940px) but if I try and view it with a device that has a max solution of 768px the grid items are no longer centered. Is this possible to do using the current setup?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that I solved setting the max-width to an outer div.

Give this a try:

JS

```
$('#container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    isFitWidth: true,
    columnWidth: 155
});
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 940px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #wrapper {
        max-width: 728px;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <ul>
            <li class="item">item</li>
            <li class="item">item</li>
            <li class="item">item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```